# How to add custom module dropdown in magento 2 luma theme top bar

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0

I want to add a dropdown(i.e select) in the top bar(which contains the welcome message) of magento 2 luma theme as the last item of it or any other theme that contains this block. This dropdown will be of my custom module. What I have tried till now is:

Setup a new module, which is working file.

Created these files and cleared the cache.

Magento mode is set to developer.

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="top.links">
        <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Html\Dropdown" name="some_name" template="Vendor_ModuleName::html/dropdown.phtml" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/template/html/dropdown.phtml

```
<select>
    <?php echo $block->getOptionsHtml(); ?>
</select>
```

> Vendor/ModuleName/Block/Html/Dropdown.phtml

```
class Dropdown extends Template
{
    private $options = [
    ['value' => 'some value 1', 'selected' => 1],
    ['value' => 'some value 2', 'selected' => 0],
    ['value' => 'some value 3', 'selected' => 0]
];

/**
 * Dropdown constructor.
 *
 * @param TemplateContext $context
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(TemplateContext $context, array $data = [])
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getOptionsHtml()
{
    $optionHtml = '';
    foreach ($this->options as $option) {
        $optionHtml .= '<option value="' . $option["value"] . '" ' . ($option["selected"] ? "selected" : "") . '>' . $option . '</option>';
    }
    return $optionHtml;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some changes for you:

`referenceContainer` to become `referenceBlock`

and `top.links` to be `header.links`

Now, once you have done all these changes, you will see some minor issues in your block:

below is a code working for me:

```
class Dropdown extends Template
{
    private $options = [
        ['value' => 'some value 1', 'label' => 'Some Laberl 1', 'selected' => 1],
        ['value' => 'some value 2', 'label' => 'Some Laberl 2', 'selected' => 0],
        ['value' => 'some value 3', 'label' => 'Some Laberl 3', 'selected' => 0]
    ];

    public function getOptionsHtml()
    {
        $optionHtml = '';
        foreach ($this->options as $option) {
            $optionHtml .= '<option value="' . $option["value"] . '" ' . ($option["selected"] ? "selected" : "") . '>' . $option['label'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $optionHtml;
    }
}
```

the outcome here is that your dropdown cannot be ordered like most blocks: because top.links, header.links are all having a block that implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links adn that means the children are meant to be li html element.

now, you also may want to use `<referenceBlock name="header.panel">`, with this layout selector, the select appears exactly like you describe. good luck

Comment: All the others are typo issues in it, I have edited the post. updated the folder name template to templates, cleared the cache. Still no effect.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help, I did tried this what you mentioned, but because of the css issue I thought this is not what I want. The select was showing below the links with full width.

Comment: I was expecting this, this area of the theme is quite complex to change. Hopefully with PWA these coupled frontend issues will disappear